# How to specify wildcard in application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I have an `application.properties` in a Spring Boot application. I want to specify allow all origins via a property called `cors.allow.origin`

But when I set it as below

```
cors.allow.origin='*'
```

and then using the env actuator the property is shown as

```
cors.allow.origin="'*'"
```

Is this a known thing in Spring Boot?

I want the property to be displayed as

```
cors.allowed.origin="*"
```

Any insights or Spring Boot documentation related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes are not needed in the properties file. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties